# Television show with a cross-eyed lion

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

Looking to identify a television show that I saw a long time ago.  I believe the show was from the 80's but may have been even from the late 70's.  It involved people living/working on a game preserve or national park in (what I assume is) Africa.  I believe it was 2 scientists, with a chimp and, the most unique character, a cross-eyed lion.

The episode/scene that I have stuck in my head is where one of the scientist is trying to improve the lion's eyesight by feeding it carrots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is Daktari, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daktari) or [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059977/).

There are [some scenes at youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=daktari&oq=daktari&gs_l=youtube.3...0.0.0.68475.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.)

Comment: Based on the movie Clarence the Cross-Eyed Lion. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059039/